# Span element not aligning properly in Chrome on Windows 8

Tags: css, google-chrome, alignment, html

So this is a doozy...

Our QA department reported a bug that only exists in Chrome in Windows 8. Works fine in all other browsers on all other platforms. The bug? Text within a `span` element drops down well below where it should be placed, almost the entire height of the element trying to be aligned.

I was working from home when this was reported, so I actually freshly installed Windows 8 on my iMac and installed the latest Chrome -- same version tested by QA -- but could not reproduce the bug. Everything aligned perfectly. Tried every possible screen resolution available and all was great.

So I'm back in the office today, and a QA guy handed me the laptop with Windows 8 installed, and wouldn't ya know it? The text is not aligning properly. It's a Lenovo Ultrabook. The one difference, though: a touch screen. But even disabling the touch screen (and verifying through the dev console that Chrome no longer recognizes the touch screen) didn't fix the problem.

Neither Chrome installation had any add-ons.

What should I be looking for?? Here's the code:

```
<div id="text_container">
    <span style="padding:0x;" class="textName" id="text_page">Problem Text Is Right Here</span>
</div>
```

Now...the "text_container" CSS consists of:

```
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 1024px;
```

"textName" is defined with:

```
font-size: 10em;
margin-left: 1.55%;
opacity: 0.7;
position: absolute;
text-transform: uppercase
top: 0.8em;
```

`#text_page` has no CSS defined. Again, all looks PERFECT except on the one Windows 8 device on Chrome, a touchscreen laptop that doubles as a tablet.

Comment: And I'm noticing now that the root of the problem seems to be setting the font size in "em" instead of "px". I'm told that was done intentionally to make the font size responsive...arghhh...the giveaway is that I suddenly noticed that the text is HUGE compared to how it renders in other browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your help, folks. Even though the suggestions didn't help, I still appreciate the time.

Anyway, I fixed the issue, and yes, it was based on my observation that the font size was measured in "em". Now, I've been doing web site programming of some kind of another for literally twenty years, and this definitely falls under the "learn something new every day" category...

I always use "px", but again, the person who coded this wanted the font to be scalable, so "em" was the way to go. Now, what I didn't know was that "em" calculates itself based on the base font size...and since the base font size wasn't defined, I guess it's up to the browser to decide on what the base font size should be. Using the dev tools, it seems that the browsers were defaulting to 16px as the base font size...

...except for Chrome on the Windows 8 laptop we have, which was setting the base font size to 24px. Upon further examination, the laptop has a pretty freakin' high screen resolution: 3200 x 1800, so I'm guessing that had an effect on it somehow. It would also explain why I couldn't reproduce the problem on Chrome in Windows 8 on my iMac -- my iMac only goes up to something like 1920 x something, so I couldn't get nearly the screen rez.

So I went into the CSS and set the body's `font-size` attribute to 16px, and that fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

May be the default value of the `vertical-align` property on your span tag is not set, so it is defaulting to "baseline".

[According to the HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/global.html#h-7.5.4), `<span>` is an inline element and `<div>` is a block element. Now that can be changed using the `display` CSS property but there is one issue: in terms of HTML validation, you can't put block elements inside inline elements so:

```
<span>...<div>foo</div>...</span>
```

is not strictly valid even if you change the `<div>` to `inline` or `inline-block`.

So, if your element is `inline` or `inline-block` use a `<span>`. If it's a `block` level element, use a `<div>`.

Comment: It's the other way around; the span is within a div. I tried changing the span to both inline and inline-block but that didn't make a difference.